# Using rcc tool with Qt6 to convert .qrc to .py resource file

Tags: pyqt6, qt6

Installing [rcc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/rcc.html) tool on Ubuntu 22.04 from the package qt6-base-dev-tools is returning error `rcc: could not find a Qt installation of ''`. The other way to convert these would be by using PySide6 pyside6-rcc, but I would like to do it without installing PySide6.

I tried to fix it with [similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/1460242), but the provided solutions did not fix it. This error is maybe rooted in the qtchooser package based on this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtchooser/+bug/1964763).